# Error while installing ruby on rails on server

Tags: ruby-on-rails

After installing rvm when i run this

> `source $HOME/rvm/scripts/rvm`

i get error

```
-bash: /root/rvm/scripts/rvm: No such file or directory
```

Comment: Tell me How did you Installed RVM. Was that as the `root` user Or as a user with access to sudo?

Comment: try running this 'rvm -v' and show the output.

Comment: root user and the output of 'rvm -v' `rvm 1.22.3 (stable) by Wayne E. Seguin <wayneeseguin@gmail.com>, Michal Papis <mpapis@gmail.com> [https://rvm.io/]`

Answer (score 0):

reference: [Problem deploying Ruby+RVM and daemontools](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6034602/problem-deploying-rubyrvm-and-daemontools)

> I found the answer but looking at the rvmsudo script installed with
>   rvm, here is a working run script:

```
#!/bin/sh
# redirect stderr to stdout
exec 2>&1

cd /app
# load rvm
. /usr/local/rvm/scripts/rvm

# select ruby version for this application
rvm use 1.9.1
# # depending on your configuration you may need to provide the absolute path to rvm, like that:
# /usr/local/bin/rvm use 1.9.1

# build the exec command line preserving the rvm environment
command="exec sudo -u app_user /usr/bin/env PATH='$PATH'"

[[ -n "${GEM_HOME:-}" ]] && command="${command} GEM_HOME='$GEM_HOME' "
[[ -n "${GEM_PATH:-}" ]] && command="${command} GEM_PATH='$GEM_PATH' "

# this is where your real command line goes
command="${command} ruby main.rb"

# run the application
eval "${command}"
```

Answer (score 0):

Try source ~/.rvm/scripts/rvm. Exit out of your current shell and then try again it should work.